# Is it possible to send an invoice number with an authorize.net refund request?

Tags: e-commerce, authorize.net

Is it possible to send the invoiceNumber field in an AIM XML refund request with Authorize.Net? I try some variations on how to do it based on the [documentation](http://www.authorize.net/support/AIM_guide_XML.pdf), and I get errors like:

> The element 'transactionRequest' in namespace
>   'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has invalid child element
>   'invoiceNumber' in namespace
>   'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'. List of possible elements
>   expected: 'authCode, refTransId, splitTenderId, order, lineItems, tax,
>   duty, shipping, taxExempt, poNumber, customer, billTo, shipTo,
>   customerIP, cardholderAuthentication, retail, transactionSettings,
>   userFields' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'

The reason I ask is because I'd like to have my refunds tie back to their original transaction for reporting reasons. That way, I can search on an invoice number and find where the purchase record came in, along with each refund record, all of which would share the same invoice number. As is now, the Authorize.Net system shows me no way to match a given customer's original purchase with their refund.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for responding to an old post, but the above answer is not correct.

To have the invoice number associate with the transaction and appear in your Auth.net transaction logs, include the following bit of XML:

```
<order><invoiceNumber>123456</invoiceNumber></order>
```

See the schema https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd within <xs:complexType name="transactionRequestType"> to view the necessary order (because order does matter).

In the above example, it would go here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<createTransactionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name>yourloginid</name>
    <transactionKey>yourtransactionkey</transactionKey>
  </merchantAuthentication>
  <refId>15444549</refId>
  <transactionRequest>
    <transactionType>refundTransaction</transactionType>
    <amount>5</amount>
    <payment>
      <creditCard>
        <cardNumber>XXXX1111</cardNumber>
        <expirationDate>122016</expirationDate>
      </creditCard>
    </payment>
    <authCode>2165668159</authCode>
    <order>
      <invoiceNumber>123456</invoiceNumber>
    </order>
  </transactionRequest>
</createTransactionRequest>
```